# Rspec undefined method 'helpers' for ActionDispatch Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

I'm upgrading an old rails 3 app to rails 5 and also upgrading Rspec in the process.  When running test, I get an error:

```
 NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `helpers' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection:0x007ffaf09d9200>
```

whenever I call be_success on a response.  See example:

```
 it "renders 'OK' text when request is html" do
      get :ping
      expect(response).to be_success
      response.body.should == 'OK'
    end
```

I get the error when I run this test. After inserting a breakpoint, I see the error is thrown whenever be_success is called...

```
(byebug) be_success
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `helpers' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection:0x007ffaf09d9200>
Did you mean?  helper_names
```

I have included config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers in my spec_helper file (had a similar issue with using rails routes paths), but it hasn't helped for this error.

Comment: What type of rspec test is this?  It looks like a `routing` spec as seen here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs.  I suspect that this error is happening because of a difference in configuration between your old version of rspec and the new one.  The current version of rspec you're upgrading to and which you're upgrading from may be helpful as well.

Comment: I encounter the same problem within a "classical" controller test with RSpec (rspec-rails v3.0.2) of a Rails engine when upgrading from Rails 4.2.4 to Rails 5.0.0. My failing example has the form  `it { expect{ get :new, params: { … } }.to change{ MyModel.count }.by(1) }`. It fails with the same error message as specified by xeroshogun.