# RSpec tests failing with undefined method `respond_with'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working on a [Rails API Tutorial](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_three) and facing an error. Whenever I run my tests, I get

```
  1) Api::V1::UsersController PUT/PATCH #update when is not created
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_with 422 }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `respond_with' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiV1UsersController::PUTPATCH
Update::WhenIsNotCreated:0x007f860e070eb8>
       Did you mean?  respond_to
```

I found two other posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030916/rspec-controller-test-failing-with-rails-api-undefined-method-helpers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647346/rspec-undefined-method-helpers-for-actiondispatch-routing)) that are pointing to a very similar problem, but both of them are not solved. Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs), instead of:

```
it { should respond_with 422 }
```

Try this:

```
it { expect(response).to have_http_status(422) }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Turns out with `shoulda-matchers` 3+, they scoped the matchers to their type of specs. So Controller specs would get the Controller matchers and not the Model matcher, etc. `respond_with` is a Controller matcher. So if you are running an assertion outside of the Controller specs then it will not be available to you and you should use `have_http_status` instead. Again, thanks!